# Braintree use hosted fields to update payment method data

Tags: angularjs, node.js, braintree

I use Braintree with NodeJS and AngularJS and need to update payment method data. I want to use hosted fields because of safety and validation, but `paymentMethod.update()` method of Braintree SDK requires card data to be passed in form like that:

```
gateway.paymentMethod.update(payMethodToken, {
    cardholderName: req.body.update.name,
    cvv: req.body.update.cvv,
    expirationDate:  req.body.update.exp
}
```

and it seems imposible to get this data from hosted fields. So, is there a way to somehow transform data from hosted fields submit to data I can pass into `paymentMethod.update()`? If not, what can be another safe way to update payment method data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

Hosted Fields prevents you from ever interacting with the credit card number or cvv. Instead, if you want to update a user's payment information, call update with a [paymentMethodNonce](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/payment-method/update/node#payment_method_nonce), using the nonce your client receives from Braintree upon form submission. Optionally, [you may also include non-Hosted Field information](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/payment-method/update/node#updating-with-a-nonce-and-additional-parameters) that you would like associated with that payment method.